# Show alert after reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried this function but it displays the `alert` then refreshes the form. I want something that refreshes the page and then displays the `alert`. How can I do that?

```
 $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var address = $('#to_address').val();
    var amount  =  $('#amount').val();
    var this_email  =  $('#this_email').val();
    var this_bal  =  $('#this_bal').val();
   if(address != '' && amount != '' && this_email != '' && this_bal != '' )
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"WithdrawChk.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{address:address, amount:amount, this_email:this_email, this_bal:this_bal},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("All Fields are required");
   }
  });
```

Comment: As soon as the `reload()` is called no further JS is executed. To have something occur after the page is reloaded you need to set the state of the page in order to show it, by cookie, localStorage, querystring etc.

Comment: Also note that reloading the page after making an AJAX request makes the entire point of AJAX redundant. I'm not sure why you're doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
        success: function(data) {
          window.sessionStorage.setItem("successData" , JSON.stringify(data));
          window.location.reload();            
       }

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("successData")){
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert-success">' + JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("successData")) + '</div>');             
}
})
```

Make sure to clear the session storage before the ajax call. And you can store only string values in the local or session storage so you have to stringify the json object to store it in session storage , and then if you want to use it , you have to parse that.

Comment: In the document ready function, data would be `undefined` as you've not saved it anywhere.

Comment: @Steve In the document ready function , it will not even go inside if loop , because of the condition. Only once it is set it will go in the if loop and for data part ,let me edit the answer to display the data part as well.

Comment: The page would be refreshed by then with the line `window.location.reload();` and data would be undefined as I said already. Even after that, data is scoped only to the success function and wouldn't be accessible to document ready.

Comment: @Steve , Yeah i missed the data part. I was just writing about how he can display alert even after page reload. Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my answer, hope it is correct now.

Comment: im editing my post and adding whole javascript function plz have a look. i dnt understand what u people are saying

Comment: @Atulkumarsingh I'm down voting this question as after the OP has now now totally changed his code to look nothing like the original question and we both spent time answering.

Answer (score 0):

As per Rorys suggestion you can store the data in localStorage and check for if it exists on the jQuery page ready function.

```
 var localStorage = window.localStorage;

 $(function(){
        var data = localStorage.getItem("data");
        if(data !== null){
            $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert-success">' + JSON.parse(data) + '</div>');
            localStorage.removeItem("data");
        }
 });


  success: function(data) {
      localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data);
      window.location.reload();
  }
```